# Is opencv::flann:Index knnsearch thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, openmp

I am trying to parallelize my ML problem with flann Index. My code in nutshell looks like this:

```
Index index(dict, KDTreeIndexParams(TREE_NUM)); // HUGE dict, very expensive to construct -- prefer to create it once.
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < featuresize; i++) {
    // creating thread-local params
    auto denseTF = index.knnSearch(<thread-local params>);
    // not relevant code
}
```

I looked up documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d49/classcv_1_1flann_1_1Index__.html#a737e306afc5003a01ef486d49303f682) but there is nothing about thread safety there.
My concern is whether this snippet is thread safe?

Comment: The documentation is a bit lacky with that respect, isn't it? Since that information is crucial in your case, have you considered asking OpenCV developers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a day of debugging and catching a data race and reading through source code ([here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp) ) I can conclude that `index.knnSearch` is NOT thread safe.

Internally, `indexTree` is being updated on `knnSearch` call. I solved this issue by creating a copy of `index` for each thread (yes, it is expensive, but still faster than sequential code).

Comment: Hey, unfortunately your source code link is just to the general file, and does not link a stable revision. Do you happen to know why searching isn't threadsafe? Shouldn't it be a readonly operation, thus automatically being threadsafe?

Comment: How exactly did you create the copies of the index? I cannot find any copy constructor.